# Find Special elements in a m*n matrix

Tags: java, matrix, dynamic-programming

My question is about to find the distinct number of positional elements in an m*n matrix which are either the minimum or maximum in their corresponding row or column. **Below is my piece of code.**

```
static void findSpecialElement(int[][] matrix)  
{  
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)  
    {  
        int rowMin = matrix[i][0];               
        int colIndex = 0;           
        boolean specialElement = true;

        for (int j = 1; j < matrix[i].length; j++)
        {
            if(matrix[i][j] < rowMin)
            {
                rowMin = matrix[i][j];                     
                colIndex = j;
            }
        } 
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++)
        {
            if(matrix[j][colIndex] > rowMin)
            {
                specialElement = false;                     
                break;
            }
        }

        if(specialElement)
        {
            System.out.println("Special Element is : "+rowMin);
        }
    }
}
```

For e.g: Given a matrix of size 3*3, the elements are stored as follows

```
1  3  4
5  2  9
8  7  6
```

**The expected output is 7**

**Leaving 5** and **3** all other numbers in the matrix have **either min or max** in row and column.So, **7 out of 9 numbers** have min or max values.

Then **7** is the **output**

Please **return -1**, if **any row** or **any column** has **multiple minimum** or **maximum** elements...

My **error** is am **failing** to get the expected **answer 7** as **per** the **question**.

Comment: Not only you dropped your homework here without showing any attempt, you didn't even post the full question. Please go over https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Guy  Sorry i have attempted many times but the output was failing..

Comment: @lancerfree but you didn't show us your attempts and your errors, how can you learn if you don't correct your mistakes?. We'll willing to help you to correct these mistakes. Please edit your question and add your code and error.

Comment: @RafaelPalomino Thanks for the suggestion...I have edited the question..if possible please try to help  me..

Comment: @lancerfree At the moment, is missing one of the parentheses '}', so it won't compile. Also, bad identation difficults the task to understand how you're trying to do in you function. Pd: I'll see how can I help you from my workplace.

Comment: @Rafael Palomino. Thanks for my error and for your help...

Comment: @Guy i hope you understood my question correctly now

Comment: @lancerfree I don't, it isn't clear why the output should be 7.

Comment: @Guy In my example of 3*3 matrix  leaving 5 and 3 all other numbers have either min and max  in row and column as i mentioned.So, totally 9 out of 7 numbers have either min and max in row and column.Coming to 5 and 3 number it neither have min nor have max in row and column. So , the expected output is 7.  You have to find the numbers in a matrix which have either min and max in row and column.....I hope you understood now

Comment: @Guy i also confused same like you when i saw the question  first time....Actually question is clear but we don't have time to read it properly and execute it as per the output..

Comment: @user3181365  i hope you know the answer to my question..

Comment: @RafaelPalomino Did you get anything from your workplace..Please try to help me ..i am also trying my best to get the correct output as per the question..

Comment: @200_success can you help me in solving this question..

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are looking for this-

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

string ltrim(const string &);
string rtrim(const string &);
vector<string> split(const string &);


// Complete the countSpecialElements function below.
int countSpecialElements(vector<vector<int>> matrix) {

int m = matrix.size();          //rows
int n = matrix[0].size();       //columns



int maxrow[102] , minrow[102];
int maxcol[102], mincol[102];
for(int p=0;p<102;p++){
    maxrow[p] =0 ;
    maxcol[p] = 0;
    minrow[p]=0;
    mincol[p]=0;
}

int k=0;
int i,j;

for(i=0;i<m;i++){
    int rminn = INT_MAX;
    int rmaxx = INT_MIN;
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        if(matrix[i][j]==rmaxx || matrix[i][j]==rminn) return -1;
        if(matrix[i][j] > rmaxx ) rmaxx = matrix[i][j];
        if(matrix[i][j] < rminn) rminn = matrix[i][j];
    }
    maxrow[i] = rmaxx;
    minrow[i] = rminn;

    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        int cminn = INT_MAX;
        int cmaxx = INT_MIN;
        for(int p=0;p<m;p++){
            if(matrix[p][j]== cmaxx || matrix[p][j] == cminn) return -1;
            if(matrix[p][j] > cmaxx ) cmaxx = matrix[p][j];
            if(matrix[p][j] < cminn) cminn = matrix[p][j];
        }

        maxcol[j] = cmaxx;
        mincol[j] = cminn;
    }
}

    int cnt = 0;
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if((matrix[i][j]== maxrow[i])||(matrix[i][j]==minrow[i])||(matrix[i][j]==maxcol[j])||(matrix[i][j]==mincol[j]))
                cnt++;
        }
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on updates, I think that your problem can be simplified as: Count the items who are min or max in a row or column. If that's ok, your algorithm is wrong because:

- You're checking the min in column and row (in both at he same time)
- You're not checking the max
- You're printing the number found

So, your strategy should be something like:

- create a counter in zero
- for every item in matrix

  - check if is min in his row
  - check if is max in his row
  - check if is min in his column
  - check if is max in his column
  - if one check is ok, increase counter
- print or return the counter

That should help you.

Comment: Perfect you understood my question exactly...I tried your way but still i am failing to get the output 7...Can you please provide me a code snippet..

Answer (score 0):

```
int maxNum = matrix[0][0];   int minNum = matrix[0][0];

for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
        if(maxNum < matrix[i][j]){
        maxNum = matrix[i][j];
    }
    else if (minNum > matrix[i][j]) {
        minNum = matrix[i][j];
    }    
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be done in better=faster way but my `O(n^2)`:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {
    public static int[][] input = {
            {1, 3, 4},
            {5, 2, 9},
            {8, 7, 6}
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numberOfElements = 0;
        Set<Integer> numberOfUniqueElements = new HashSet<>();

        Set<Integer> specialElements = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            int maxInRow = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            int minInRow = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            int maxInColumn = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            int minInColumn = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            for (int j = 0; j < input[i].length; j++) {
                numberOfElements++;
                numberOfUniqueElements.add(input[i][j]);
                if (input[i][j] > maxInRow) {
                    maxInRow = input[i][j];
                }
                if (input[i][j] < minInRow) {
                    minInRow = input[i][j];
                }
                if (input[j][i] > maxInColumn) {
                    maxInColumn = input[j][i];
                }
                if (input[j][i] < minInColumn) {
                    minInColumn = input[j][i];
                }
            }

            specialElements.add(minInRow);
            specialElements.add(maxInRow);
            specialElements.add(minInColumn);
            specialElements.add(maxInColumn);
        }
        if (numberOfUniqueElements.size() != numberOfElements) {
            System.out.println("-1");
        } else {
            System.out.println(specialElements.size());
        }
    }
}
```